# Como percorrer uma ViewBag e popular uma table cshtml

Tags: c#

Essa é minha ViewBag

```
public ActionResult Details(AzureDiscountGroupModel model)
        {
            var reseller = _resellerService.QueryAll();

            ViewBag.DetailReseller = reseller.Where(x => x.AzureDiscountGroupId == model.Id);

            return View(model);
        }
```

E como eu pego esses campos no cshtml e populo um Grid(table) do tipo?

```
<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>AzureDiscountGroup</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descricao)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Descricao)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PercDesconto)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PercDesconto)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Nome")?????
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Desc")??????
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.DetailReseller)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Display(item.Name)???????????
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PercDesconto)???????????
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

**EDIT1**

Fiz isso e está vindo vazia a tabela

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.DetailReseller as IEnumerable<Reseller>)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Display(item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.Display(item.Alias)
            </td>
            @*<td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>*@
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Tem certeza que o `reseller.Where()` não traz uma coleção vazia?

Comment: @VictorLaio, tenho sim.

Comment: O problema é que está vindo sim, os registros, no meu caso 10, mas não consigo exibilos na tela assim: `@Html.Display(item.Descricao)` por exemplo

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi, não era para colocar um @Html.Display e sim isso

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.DetailReseller as IEnumerable<Reseller>)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
               @item.Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Alias
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```